# Where is my Steam Folder?

Tags: steam, pc

It's not where it's supposed to be, which is This PC > OS (C:) > Program Files (x86) > Then it should be there under steam. But it's not! I've searched all over my PC and it's not there. Where can I find it? Below is where it should be.

[image]

Comment: Try a search in the C: drive? It may take a while.  I assume you don't have any other disks it may have been placed in also.

Comment: I dont think it is reliable solution to "search in drive X" simply because Steam can be installed in any folder on drive, and if you have mess like I have on your system drive (or more than one drive, how about that?) then question actually makes more sense than it looks like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open Steam, open task manager, right click on steam, click on open folder location, similar to this:

[image: open folder location dialog]

Steam should be located on the folder it opens. This is more reliable than the library based method because the library folder might be located on somewhere other than steam's folder.

Answer (score 3):

If you are able to launch Steam you can check in the client by going to Steam>Settings>Downloads>Steam Library Folders

[image]
[image]